# Django - per url authentication?

Tags: django, cordova, django-authentication

I have built a web application using the Django web framework. For security, I created some middleware to ensure each URL is password protected. If some random person enters a URL of the webapp, but aren't logged in, the middleware kicks them to the login page.

Now I'm trying to build an iOS app which will post and access data to/from that same server which runs the larger web application. The idea is that the iOS app will make URL calls to the server and the server will spit back JSON data. I'm building the app with PhoneGape, so its all straight forward URL calls in jQuery.

The problem is, since the web application requires the user to be logged in to do anything, I need some way to allow the iOS app to make a request for data and have the server somehow validate that this request is allowed, even though the user isn't logged in. Basically something along the lines of a per-url validation (but without logging the user in).

I think my best bet is to use that same middleware, but extend it so that for any URL that comes through that begins with `/m/ios/` is handled differently. From the app side, I can have it so that any URL it requests, it also attaches the `username` and `password` of the user onto that URL. Thus the middleware can scrape off the username/password and verify its a valid user, but not log the user in and simply carry out the request.

Is this a logical way to handle this situation? Is there a better way?

---

**EDIT I should say, I'm quite open to approaching this differently if what I'm doing is inappropriate/insecure**

---

Here's my middleware file as it stands, but it isn't working correctly. The validation works, but the final call to the URL isn't completed.

```
   from django.contrib.auth.views import login
   from django.contrib.auth import authenticate
   from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect, HttpResponse
   from django.utils import simplejson
   from django.core import serializers

   class SiteLogin:
       "This middleware requires a login for every view"
       def process_request(self, request):
          if request.path != '/accounts/login/' and request.user.is_anonymous():
              try:
                  url = request.path.split('/')[1]
                  url = url + '/' + request.path.split('/')[2] + '/'
                  print(url)
                  if url == 'm/ios/':
                      usr = request.GET['username']
                      psw = request.GET['password']
                      user = authenticate(username = usr, password = psw)
                      if user is not None:
                          if user.is_active:
                              # This line doesn't actually carry out the request
                              return login(request)
                      else:
                          d = {}
                          d['creds_good'] = "false"
                          json = simplejson.dumps(d)
                          GET = request.GET
                          callback = GET.get('callback')

                          if callback:
                              json = '%s(%s)' % (callback, json)

                          return HttpResponse(json, mimetype='application/json')
              except:
                  pass

              if request.POST:
                  return login(request)
              else:
                  return HttpResponseRedirect('/accounts/login/?next=%s' % request.path)
```

Comment: is there a reason you don't want to login the user for the ios requests?

Comment: Is it possible to log them in and have that session stay logged in, even on a cell phone app with cell coverage? How long would that login session last? Would there be issues with them loosing cell reception? Basically I was thinking it would be better to do one-off authentications to keep the user 'mobile' so to speak. I guess I don't really have an answer to your question, I just sort of assumed it wasn't the best idea...

Comment: Passing the password on the URL is extremely insecure. It is vulnerable to URL sniffing. As @toad013 mentioned you can login and the cookies will be passed in each request, if you use normal Django auth.

Comment: Alright, so login once - stays logged in. There's no issue with loosing cell coverage and having to re-login?

Comment: After some testing, it doesn't seem that the cookies are passed in each request. Remember, I'm running an app on my phone that was built with PhoneGap. I'm not sure if that affects this at all, but after testing it looks like the user is "anonymous" for every request. I put in `print` statements throughout a that middleware (a revised version) and each URL is coming from an unknown (not logged in) user. Perhaps I'm not correctly logging them in? I'm not sure...

Comment: Did you achieve your login issue?

Answer (score 1):

Django has a [login_required](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/auth/default/#the-login-required-decorator) decorator you can use for this.
You can map urls to views such that certain urls require login and others don't

Comment: But I have a LOT of urls, and as mentioned, have a blanket "login required". So this isn't really applicable.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't put the username and password in the url of the request. That stuff can be seen plaintext. This also leads me to believe that you're ios app caches my username and password. Which is a security risk in itself.

According to your current middleware logic, you are still logging in the user. It also looks like that you're logging in the user per url for the ios requests, creating a new session per login/url.

If you're app doesn't support http cookies then passing a key or token of somesort is the best way, essentially the same as a cookie but doing it manually.I would try to leverage django's session and auth as much as possible. In the ios app I would collect the username and password and call login right after. Ideally it would return a long lasting session (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/sessions/#django.contrib.sessions.backends.base.SessionBase.set_expiry) to ios app and the app will ONLY store the returned session key. Which is what you would use for auth in place of username/password credentials for all other requests. The session won't die if the phone looses reception as long as the phone retains the session key, the session doesn't live on the phone it lives on the server.

If possible I would attach the session key in the headers of all the requests after (for the sake of this example I'll call the header DJANGO_SESSION_KEY), that way it's in the same place for all types of requests (POST, GET, PUT, etc.)

Then I would extend django's session middleware and rewrite the process_request function. In the version of django i'm using (1.5), I would change the line that looks for the session_key in the process_request function.

```
class MySessionMiddleware(SessionMiddleware):                                                   
    def process_request(self, request):                                            
        engine = import_module(settings.SESSION_ENGINE)                            
        session_key = request.COOKIES.get(settings.SESSION_COOKIE_NAME, request.META.get('HTTP_DJANGO_SESSION_KEY'))   
        request.session = engine.SessionStore(session_key)
```

I would then use this custom extended session middleware in lieu of django's in the settings.py.

Then your custom middleware comes it, defined at the end of the request middleware chain.

```
def process_request(self, request):                                                
    if request.path != '/accounts/login/' and request.user.is_anonymous():         
        if request.META.HTTP_CONTENT_TYPE == 'application/json' or request.META.HTTP_ACCEPT == 'application/json':
            # return json error response                                           
        # return error redirect
```